# Proposal for tag: [symmetry]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently asked a question in which I think we need a [symmetry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry) tag, which has not been created yet.

Here are some questions to which I think the tag would be applied to:

- [The symmetry of months](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160993/the-symmetry-of-months?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C44.5927)
- [I'm symmetric, not palindromic!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142248/im-symmetric-not-palindromic?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C17.4701)
- [Is this skew symmetry?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193955/is-this-skew-symmetry?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C42.0910)

And another one, which I could have found earlier to prevent myself from posting a dupe, and which came easily in [this search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=symmetry) is the following post,

[Numbers with Rotational Symmetry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77866/numbers-with-rotational-symmetry?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C37.4338)

Anyways, I think we need such a tag. Any thoughts?

Comment: The tag is kinda broad/vague. The symmetry in the skew symmetry question is a different symmetry than in the palindrome question, so I think this'd be a much better proposal if you could include a brief [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) draft to demonstrate exactly *what* the scope of the tag would be

Comment: I'm not sure how different this tag would be than just searching for the word "symmetry".

Answer (score -2):

I am **in favor** of the proposal. And, here is my tag wiki proposal,

> For challenges involving some sort of symmetry, or intending to produce symmetrical output in any form.

Also, [symmetry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry) is an elemental part of [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), just like

[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) [primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes) [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) [graph-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations) [polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) [rational-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) and many more...

Further, I have also noted that some of the questions (which appeared in [this search query](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=symmetry+is%3Aquestion)) are not having any relevant tag which points to symmetry, or any similar meaning. And, this search query isn't the whole list, actually!